# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'category' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, import

I have been coding around to create a shopping cart for my online store project. I have a table named "products" and an entity class from this table as followed;

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author fet
 */

@Entity

@Table(name = "products")

@NamedQueries({

    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByProductId", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.productId = :productId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByProductName", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.productName = :productName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findBySubCategoryName", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.subCategoryName = :subCategoryName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByCategoryName", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.categoryName = :categoryName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByCompanyName", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.companyName = :companyName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.price = :price"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByTags", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.tags = :tags"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByProductQty", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.productQty = :productQty"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByLastUpdated", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.lastUpdated = :lastUpdated"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Products.findByHits", query = "SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE p.hits = :hits")})
public class Products implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer productId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 60)
    @Column(name = "product-name")
    private String productName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    @Column(name = "sub-category-name")
    private String subCategoryName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    @Column(name = "category-name")
    private String categoryName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    @Column(name = "company-name")
    private String companyName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "summary")
    private String summary;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "tags")
    private String tags;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "product_qty")
    private int productQty;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "lastUpdated")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdated;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "hits")
    private int hits;

    public Products() {
    }

    public Products(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }


    public Products(Integer productId, String productName, String subCategoryName, String categoryName, String companyName, double price, String tags, int productQty, Date lastUpdated, int hits) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.price = price;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.productQty = productQty;
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
        this.hits = hits;
    }

    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getSubCategoryName() {
        return subCategoryName;
    }

    public void setSubCategoryName(String subCategoryName) {
        this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public int getProductQty() {
        return productQty;
    }

    public void setProductQty(int productQty) {
        this.productQty = productQty;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public int getHits() {
        return hits;
    }

    public void setHits(int hits) {
        this.hits = hits;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (productId != null ? productId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Products)) {
            return false;
        }
        Products other = (Products) object;
        if ((this.productId == null && other.productId != null) || (this.productId != null && !this.productId.equals(other.productId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.Products[ productId=" + productId + " ]";
    }
}
```

To handle operations I have an ejb class named "operations" as followed;

```
package ejb;

import entities.Products;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author fet
 */

@Stateless
public class operations {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "registerPU")
    private EntityManager em;


    public List<Products> retrieveProducts() {

        return  em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Products p").getResultList();
    }
}
```

and I have an xhtml file which I want to present my products;

```
<h:dataTable value="#{index.products}" var="p">

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header" />
            <h:outputLink value="index.xhtml"/>
            <f:param   name="query" value="#{p.productId}"/>

        </h:column>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </h:dataTable>
```

Finally I have RequestScoped bean named index;

```
package WEB;

import ejb.operations;
import entities.Products;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author fet
 */
@Named(value = "index")
@RequestScoped

public class index implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private operations operations;

    public index() {
    }

    public List<Products> getProducts() {
        return operations.retrieveProducts();
    }
}
```

But I am instantly getting this error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>   type Exception report
>   messageInternal Server Error
>   descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>   exception
>   javax.servlet.ServletException
>       root cause
>       javax.ejb.EJBException
>       root cause
>       javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): 
>       org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

```
Internal Exception: 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'category' in 'field list'

Error Code: 1054

Call: SELECT product_id, category-name, company-name, hits, lastUpdated, price, product-name, product_qty, sub-category-name, summary, tags FROM products

Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Products sql="SELECT product_id, category-name, company-name, hits, lastUpdated, price, product-name, product_qty, sub-category-name, summary, tags FROM products")

root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.

Any opinions or advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use hyphens in column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you use hyphens(-) in column names. Try to replace it with underscore(_).
I'm not sure if you can escape it like this:

```
@Column(name = "\`category-name\`")  
private String categoryName;
```

Comment: escaping or renaming?

Comment: First i tried escaping but however it scanned just the name of column so renamed and it solved but maybe i miss something when tried to escape